# what are the ways to integrate soap webservice with Apache camel give some example

Tags: jbossfuse

I have a Soap web service deployed in one Application Server. We want to integrate that Soap Webservice with Apache Camel in another application server (JBoss Fuse) server. Are there some guidelines available?

Answer (score 0):

What is the application server that hosts the webservice? What language/technology is the webservice coded in? What (broadly) will the Camel route do.

Camel provides a heap of different data input endpoints -- direct memory, HTTP, FTP, files, SOAP, etc., etc. Connecting your webservice to Camel comes down to choosing one of these that endpoints that your webservice can use. Camel offers a huge amount of flexibility in how it accepts and responds to data, and the choice of an approach really depends on the needs of your application, and how it is developed.